# How to use the mapper created by Mapstruct as @Mock during testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, springmockito

**The context**

I have a simple test method testFindByUserName. I use mockito library. I have @Mock UserMapper which is created by Mapstruct library.

**The problem**

Mocito doesn't handle Static method INSTANCE which I use to mapping user to userDto. I have error : error:org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

How resolve this problem.

**The code**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceImplTest {

private User user;

private String token;

private UserDto userDto;


@InjectMocks
private UserServiceImpl userService;

@Mock
private UserMapper userMapper;

@Before
public void before() {
    user = new User(2L, "User_test",
            "firstName_test", "lastName_test",
            "test@test.pl", true, "password_test",
            "address_test", null,new ArrayList<>(),new ArrayList<>(), new HashSet<>());
    token = "test_token";
    userDto = new UserDto(2L, "User_test",
            "firstName_test", "lastName_test",
            "test@test.pl", true, "password_test",
            "address_test", null,new ArrayList<>(),new ArrayList<>(), new HashSet<>());

}

@Test
public void testFindByUsername() throws Exception {
    //Given
    String username= "User_test";

    when(userMapper.INSTANCE.userToUserDto(userRepository.findByUsername(username))).thenReturn(userDto);
    //When
    UserDto result = userService.findByUsername(username);

    //Then
    assertEquals("User_test", result.getUsername());
    assertEquals("firstName_test", result.getFirstName());
    assertEquals("lastName_test", result.getLastName());
    assertEquals("test@test.pl", result.getEmail());
    assertEquals("password_test", result.getPassword());
    assertEquals("address_test", result.getAddress());

}
```

method which I testing

```
@Override
public UserDto findByUsername(final String username)  {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        LOGGER.info("Not found user");
    }
        return mapper.INSTANCE.userToUserDto(user);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method) to test static methods inside Mockito test, using the following steps:

> ```
> @PrepareForTest(Static.class) // Static.class contains static methods
> ```
>
> Call PowerMockito.mockStatic() to mock a static class (use PowerMockito.spy(class) to mock a specific method):
>
> ```
> PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
> ```
>
> Just use Mockito.when() to setup your expectation:
>
> ```
> Mockito.when(Static.firstStaticMethod(param)).thenReturn(value);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by borrowing Spring's AplicationContext mechanism for (transitive) initialization of Mappers.

Disclaimer: this might only work if you use mappers with Spring and `componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING`

Say you have a CarMapper which also uses a transitive WheelMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = SPRING, uses = {WheelMapper.class})
public interface CarMapper {
    CarDto map(Car car);
}
```

Then in your test code, you create a Spring `@Configuration` which imports the generated Mapstruct mapper implemantations (which also comes in handy in your Spring based tests):

```
@Configuration
@Import({ CarMapperImpl.class, WheelMapperImpl.class })
public class TestMapperConfiguration {}
```

And then you build a mapper resolver for your tests which uses Spring magic to resolve transitive beans by using the `@Configuration`:

```
public class MapperResolver {

    private static ApplicationContext context = buildContext();

    private static ApplicationContext buildContext() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = 
           new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.register(TestMapperConfiguration.class);
        annotationConfigApplicationContext.refresh();
        return annotationConfigApplicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getMapper(Class<T> clazz) {
        return context.getBean(clazz);
    }
}
```

And finally you can use that resolver in your Mockito tests (this example uses Mockito for JUnit5):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyClazzTest {

        @Spy
        private CarMapper carMapper = MapperResolver.getMapper(CarMapper.class);

        @InjectMocks
        private MyClazz sut;

        @Test
        public void someTest() {
            sut.doSomething();
            //...
        }
}
```